# Variable class reassignment not working

Tags: python

I am making an adventure game, and I have too check which class the player is, but the game does not reassign the character, so the player is still none type after being set to person.

```
character = None
def start():
characterchosen = False
printslow("Welcome adventurer. Chose wisely.")
sleep(2)
charactername = input("What is your name? ")
print("Characters:")
print("1. Person")
while characterchosen == False:
    character = input("Please chose a character: ")
    characterchosen = True
    if character == "1":
        character = person(charactername)
    else:
        characterchosen = False
        print("Invalid Response. Please try again.")
print("Great! Now that you have chosen your class, your mission may begin.")
gameone()

def gameone():
if type(character) == "<class 'person'>":
    print("game here")

start()
```

When I used print(type(character)) I got `<class 'NoneType'>`
**UPDATE:**
I tried setting the check to NoneType, but I still get nothing, even though the function is being called.

Comment: so, what is the question?

Comment: Please fix your indentation.  The code you posted won't load.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code. Where's the definition of the `person` class? But anyway, the `character` in the `start` function is local to the `start` function, it's not the same object as the  `character` in the global context at the top of the script.

Comment: The `character` in `start` is a local variable that does not change the external `character`.

Comment: In the future please make sure your code is properly formatted and complete. We can't run it if you don't include the `person` class, for example.

Comment: Also, `type` doesn't return a string, it returns a `type` object.  Try `type(type(character))`.  Use `isinstance(character, person)` instead

Comment: Thanks! Sorry about the indentation, my code isn't very neat and I didn't have time to upload the person class, so I am sorry that I forgot to include that. And I did try is instance earlier, but it didn't work with the way I set it up so I tried type, but when I tried is instance again it worked. Thank you all for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you refer to the `character` variable inside your `start` function, it's assigning to a variable in the local scope (function scope). To let Python know you mean the `character` variable you defined in the global scope, you have to explicitly state so:

```
def start():
    global character
    characterchosen = False
    printslow("Welcome adventurer. Chose wisely.")
    ...
```

You're also comparing the result of `type` to a string representation of that type. What you want is to compare it to the type directly:

```
if type(character) == person:
    print("game here")
```

Or better yet, use the `isinstance` built-in function:

```
if isinstance(character, person):
    print("game here")
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to define it as global and assign it at the same time, and I was getting invalid syntax. This helped a lot!